# How to correctly setup multiple IP addresses pointing to one instance in EC2?

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

I currently have one ec2 instance which I'd like to have 2 public IPs pointing to. I have 2 EIPs allocated, 2 network interfaces to which the EIPs are attached and which are both attached to the single EC2 instance running ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. The seccond EIP and network interface were added recently, and there is indeed an `eth1` that pops up, although I currently have to manually run `dhclient`, but that's not the problem. The problem is that no packets come through. I have triple-checked my security groups, all of them allow port 80 from any IP address. However, adding a byte-counter rule to iptables such as `iptables -A INPUT -i eth1` reveals that exactly 0 packets are reaching my machine through the second interface.

I have found & read [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/multiple-ip-addresses-for-ec2-instances-in-a-virtual-private-cloud/) but it doesn't help.

What am I missing? Is there some button I forgot to click?

Comment: Did you do the "Associate Address" portion of that Amazon link?  When you `ifconfig` does eth1 show the proper IP address you are expecting it to have?

Comment: @armani `ip addr` shows the private ip address, which I just checked is the correct one shown on the network interfaces page. Also shown on the network interfaces page is that both interfaces are associated with the correct public IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than a year later, I finally figured it out! Thanks to [this article](http://engineering.silk.co/post/31923247961/multiple-ip-addresses-on-amazon-ec2). In summary:

If you haven't already, run dhclient on the new interface:

```
# dhclient eth1
```

Then, figure out what your new private IP address is. You can either look in the EC2 console, or run

```
ip addr
```

You also need to know the gateway IP. In most cases it's `your.ip.0.1`, but just to make sure run:

```
ip route
```

And you should see something like:

```
default via 12.34.0.1 dev eth0
```

`12.34.0.1` is the gateway in this case. For demonstration I'm going to assume the private ip is `12.34.56.78`. Now run (as root):

```
ip rule add from 12.34.56.78 table 1000
ip route add default via 12.34.0.1 dev eth1 table 1000
ip route flush cache
```

To test your configuration:

```
curl --interface 12.34.56.78 ifconfig.me
```

Then, to make your changes permanent, add to your `/etc/network/interfaces` those commands and their oppposites:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
  up ip rule add from 12.34.56.78 table 1000
  up ip route add default via 12.34.0.1 dev eth1 table 1000
  down ip rule del from 12.34.56.78 table 1000
  down ip route del default via 12.34.0.1 dev eth1 table 1000
```

NOTE: Make sure that you have a snapshot of your instance before you change the persistent network settings, in case something breaks and you are not able to access your instance.

Answer (score 1):

I have correctly working ec2 instance with 2 private ip addresses, and 2 EIP, connected to them, but I used a subinterface for second IP, not another network interface

Content of /etc/network/interfaces (debian wheezy)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0 eth0:0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
post-up ifconfig eth0:0 172.31.xx.yy netmask 255.255.240.0 up
```

i dont remember the reason why I assigned an IP address to eth0:0 manually, but this setup works. Also tests with

```
curl --interface PRIVATE_IP ifconfig.me
```

shows, that outgoing traffic from eth0 and eth0:0 is really initiated from correct EIP.